# CSS Zoom property not working with BoundingClientRectangle

Tags: javascript, css, transform

I'm having trouble getting the coordinates of an element after it has been transformed using the "zoom" property. I need to know the coordinates of all 4 corners. I would typically accomplish this with the getBoundingClientRect property however, that does not seem to work correctly when the element is zoomed. I've attached a short jsfiddle link to show what doesn't seem to work. I'm using Chrome but the behavior is present on Firefox as well.

http://jsfiddle.net/GCam11489/0hu7kvqt/

HTML:

```
<div id="box" style="zoom:100%">Hello</div><div></div><div></div>
```

JS:

```
var div = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
div[1].innerHTML = "PreZoom Width: " + div[0].getBoundingClientRect().width;
div[0].style.zoom = "150%";
div[2].innerHTML = "PostZoom Width: " + div[0].getBoundingClientRect().width;
```

When I run that code, "100" is displayed for both the before and after zoom widths.

I have found a lot of information but everything I find seems to say that it was a known bug on Chrome and has since been fixed. Does anyone know how this can be corrected or what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This comment](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=429140#c8) on the bug report goes into some detail reg. the issue, but its status appears to be 'WontFix', so you're probably out of luck there.

### Some alternatives:

- If you were to use `transform: scale(1.5)` instead of zoom, you'd get the correct value in `getBoundingClientRect()`, but it would mess with the page layout.
- You could use `window.getComputedStyle(div[0]).zoom` to get the zoom value of the element (in decimals) and multiply it with the width from `getBoundingClientRect()`

Comment: You can not rely on the `window.getComputedStyle(div[0]).zoom`, because `zoom` style on parent DomNode is not reflected on current node.

Answer (score 3):

Had the issue with a tooltip component.

Created this function to fetch all zooms applied to an element. Then I used that zoom to apply it to the global tooltip as well. Once done it aligned correctly.

Notice that it checks for parents parent`el.parentElement?.parentElement`, this is so it doesn't take the global browser zoom into account.

```
export const getZoomLevel = (el: HTMLElement) : number[] => {
    const zooms = []
    const getZoom = (el: HTMLElement) => {
        const zoom = window.getComputedStyle(el).getPropertyValue('zoom')
        const rzoom = zoom ? parseFloat(zoom) : 1
        if (rzoom !== 1) zooms.push(rzoom)
        if (el.parentElement?.parentElement) getZoom(el.parentElement)
    }
    getZoom(el)
    zooms.reverse()
    return zooms
}
```

If you don't want to to zoom the 'tooltip' component would be to get rect with zoom adjusted for, like this:

```
export const getRect = (el: HTMLElement) : Partial<DOMRect> => {
    if (!el) return { x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0, top: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0, left: 0 }
    let rect = el?.getBoundingClientRect();
    const zooms = getZoomLevel(el)
    const rectWithZoom = {
        bottom: zooms.reduce((a, b) => a * b, rect.bottom),
        height: zooms.reduce((a, b) => a * b, rect.height),
        left: zooms.reduce((a, b) => a * b, rect.left),
        right: zooms.reduce((a, b) => a * b, rect.right),
        top: zooms.reduce((a, b) => a * b, rect.top),
        width: zooms.reduce((a, b) => a * b, rect.width),
        x: zooms.reduce((a, b) => a * b, rect.x),
        y: zooms.reduce((a, b) => a * b, rect.y),
    }
    return rectWithZoom
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is quite an old post but I've encountered the same problem, I have an angular material project on a small panel which has a pixel ratio of under 1 which makes everything very small. To fix that I've added a zoom on the body to counter this.

The angular material (7) slider uses `getBoundingClientRect()` to determine it's position, which made the slider go way further then I'd wish.

I've used a solution like eruditespirit mentioned above.

```js
if (Element.prototype.getBoundingClientRect) {
  const DefaultGetBoundingClientRect = Element.prototype.getBoundingClientRect;
  
  Element.prototype.getBoundingClientRect = function () {
    let zoom = +window.getComputedStyle(document.body).zoom;
    let data = DefaultGetBoundingClientRect.apply(this, arguments);

    if (zoom !== 1) {
      data.x = data.x * zoom;
      data.y = data.y * zoom;
      data.top = data.top * zoom;
      data.left = data.left * zoom;
      data.right = data.right * zoom;
      data.bottom = data.bottom * zoom;
      data.width = data.width * zoom;
      data.height = data.height * zoom;
    }

    return data;
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across this in my search for a solution.  I have a `position:absolute` element that I update the position on when the window is resized, and iOS triggers this on zooming in/out.

I discovered `window.visualViewport` which has the key information needed to offset this, including zoom information.

My solution for setting the position/size of an element with the zoom offset:

```ts
positionNavHighlight(link: HTMLElement) {
  const rect = link.getBoundingClientRect();

  const offsetTop = window.visualViewport.offsetTop;
  const offsetLeft = window.visualViewport.offsetLeft;

  navActiveBg.style.top = `${rect.top + offsetTop}px`;
  navActiveBg.style.left = `${rect.left + offsetLeft}px`;
  navActiveBg.style.height = `${rect.height}px`;
  navActiveBg.style.width = `${rect.width}px`;
}
```